# Visual Studio is reporting an error, but still compiling the program and everything works as it should. Have I made a mistake in my code?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, variadic

I have made a small header-only timer struct for testing the speed of functions. I made it purely out of curiosity because I am learning C++.

I have a function called "TimeTask" which has 2 overloads, The first one takes a std::function(void()) as a parameter and records how long the function takes to execute. The other one is a template function that takes a void function with any number of parameters and records its speed.

```
struct Timer
{
private:
    std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point begin, end;
    float Duration = 0.0f;
public:
    
    const float& getDuration() const
    {
        return Duration;
    }

    void StartTimer()
    {
        begin = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    }

    void StopTimer()
    {
        end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
        std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli> ChronoDuration = end - begin;
        Duration = ChronoDuration.count();
    }

    template<class...Args>
    void TimeTask(std::function<void(Args...)> task, Args&&...args)
    {
        StartTimer();
        task(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        StopTimer();
    }

    void TimeTask(std::function<void()> task)
    {
        StartTimer();
        task();
        StopTimer();
    }
   

};
```

Quite simple really. I tested it with the following code:

```
void task_parameters(double j) {
    for (double i = 0; i < j * j * j * j * j; i++)
    {
    };

    std::cout << "Done\n";
}

void task_void()
{
    return;
}


int main()
{

    Timer timer;

    timer.TimeTask<double>(task_parameters,15.0);
    

    std::cout << timer.getDuration() << std::endl;

    timer.TimeTask(task_void);

    std::cout << timer.getDuration() << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles and runs as expected but the first time I run the TimeTask function with "double" as my parameter type, it gives me an error:
E0304   no instance of overloaded function "Timer::TimeTask" matches the argument list

The program will still run, but I was wondering if I could get rid of this error? Thank you

The code appears to be correct and the behaves as expected, but I don't understand why that error is appearing.

Comment: I dunno what VS was thinking in allowing this to even run, errors or not, as it stands no chance on clang. Any reason you don't just use `template<class Fn, class... Args> void TimeTask(Fn&& task, Args&&...args)` for your task runner and eliminate the void version entirely? Do that, lose the `<double>` nonsense in `main` and it should work (for *both* your `task_parameters` and `task_void` setups, btw). [See it live](https://godbolt.org/z/jEPP3znhe).

Comment: Wow that did the trick. Thank you so much. I will study your solution to see where I went wrong.

Comment: There are several ways to do that; that's just one that is pretty simple. Every way has ups and downs, but for your needs that one seems pretty basic.. Anyway, good luck.

Comment: Aside: I'd be tempted to have `TimeTask` be the *only* public member, and have it return the duration.

Comment: I would also have it that way, however I would like to have the option to time a whole chunk of code instead of one function. I am still confused as to how it was able to run in the first place if I made so many mistakes. The output was identical to WhozCraig's solution. Very strange

Comment: the reason it runs is because the error you see is an intellisense error not a biuld error.

Comment: @BigMike *E0304* -- This is not a compile error.  All compile errors given by Visual C++ are prepended by `C`, for example `C1234`.  What you are seeing is an Intellisense error, and Intellisense is not the C++ compiler.  Because Intellisense gets things wrong at times, some programmers ignore it.  The only thing that matters are errors and warnings given by the compiler, not Intellisense.